# ImageMagick in R

Tags: r, imagemagick, installation

I want to use ImageMagick in R, but R won't let me install it.

```
install.packages("ImageMagick")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/FSFH-2/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘ImageMagick’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

I'm under the impression that I have the latest version of R, so what's going on here?

Additionally, I downloaded ImageMagick into windows, but I can't figure out how to get it into R. Help!

Comment: ImageMagick is not an R package, but unrelated software. You need to install it outside R.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on using imagemagick with R. But like Roland said, it's going to be external to R: http://www.r-bloggers.com/animate-gif-images-in-r-imagemagick/

Comment: If you're on Windows, I found Graphics Magick to work significantly better and with less headache.

Answer (score 13):

you need to install a package named "installr" prior to installing ImageMagick.

Simple Steps:

1. Tools->InstallPackages->installr
2. From R command Line write

   - `require(installr)`
   - `install.ImageMagick()`  (This command will by default install the latest version, u can specify the URl of the version needed)

The package will be installed !!!

Comment: This worked for me, should be top answer since its so simple

Comment: Note to Mac users that the `installr` package is only available for Windows. While you technically can download it for Mac through GitHub using `devtools::install_github("talgalili/installr")`, the command `install.ImageMagick()` still won't work because it downloads an .exe file for Win32. for Mac Users, the approach below using `install.packages("magick")` does the trick though!

Answer (score 12):

There is now a package [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/package=magick) that wraps around the [ImageMagick STL](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html).

It can be installed simply with `install.packages("magick")`

There is a blog post explaining what you can do with it here: https://ropensci.org/blog/2016/08/23/z-magick-release

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the link [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) to download and install ImageMagick on Windows. After that, type your command (like convert ...) in cmd.exe to verify that ImageMagick does exist. At this time, I know that we can only use it in cmd.exe, not in R.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac, what just worked for me was to use **Homebrew** in Terminal (if you don't have homebrew or anything similar, [get it!](http://brew.sh/)).

I installed **ImageMagick**, and then I had to install **animation** in R itself.

In terminal:

```
sudo brew install ImageMagick
```

... it installs a few package dependencies and finishes up.

In the R console afterwards (in R, Rstudio, Emacs, ...):

```
install.packages("animation")
```

Now try `?gganimate` and run the examples at the bottom to test it out!

The examples in the help file worked without problem for me. This works within Rstudio very fluidly, Rstudio being written just as a web-browser is under the hood. I personally use ESS within Emacs, which for plotting usually opens an X11 (or Quartz) window. Using `gg_animate`, however, opens a browser by default and displays the output there.

Answer (score 1):

I used these commands in RStudio.

- install.packages('installr')
- library(installr)
- install.ImageMagick()

It installed the latest version of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OS or Linux, you can install ImageMagick on your system and then use it from within R using the system() function. I don't know if ImageMagick works with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, what just worked for me was to use port in Terminal.

I installed ImageMagick, and then I had to install animation in R itself.

In terminal:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```

... it installs a few package dependencies and finishes up.

In the R studio afterwards:

```
install.packages("animation")
```

and then check by running following example:

```
saveGIF({
    for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
})
```

if the above conversion was successful, the option 'convert' should not be NULL